# MVC.NET MultiSelectList Questions

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So 2 questions, I have my html.multiselectlist working fine, however I want to do 2 things...

1. Set a default selected value from my list
2. Append a hardcoded value / entry within my list (which is pulling from a DB), which is basically a select "ALL" option.

This is my controller code, so is there where I need to perform this task, or directly within my view or viewmodel:

```
Inherits Controller

Dim _DB As New BlackBoxNormalizedEntities()

' Main / Default Lander for TFS Section
Function TFSMain() As ActionResult
    Dim AccTypeList = (From m In _DB.LibAcctType Select m).ToList()
    Dim TrxnTypeList = (From m In _DB.LibTrxnTyp Select m).ToList()
    Dim ActnCodeList = (From m In _DB.LibActnCode Select m).ToList()

    Dim viewModel As New TFS_VModel()
    viewModel.AccType = AccTypeList
    viewModel.Trxntype = TrxnTypeList
    viewModel.ActnCode = ActnCodeList
    viewModel.TStatus = viewModel.TStatus

    Return View(viewModel)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You should construct and populate your MultiSelectList within the Action as part of your ViewModel rather than in the View and present that ViewModel to the View.

Comment: The List is populated through my viewmodel, which in turns just gets passed to my view afterwards.... that works fine.... I also just managed to figure out how to append additional static values to my existing Ienumerable list.... now I just need to figure out how to set a default....

Comment: Look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470158.aspx, you provide a list of SelectedItem which indicates the 'selected' items, just provide a list of 1 with your default item.